# Is it possible to label elements in a Python list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am working on a classification problem with sklearn in Python. I need to try different algorithms and calculate a confusion matrix for my test data with each of them.

Is it possible to store those matrices in a list while still being able to refer to them as `my_list["SVM"]`, `my_list["KNN"]`, `my_list["logistic_regression"]` and so on instead of `my_list[0]`, `my_list[1]`...?

If not possible, what data structure should I use instead?

Comment: Looks like you need a python `dictionary`

Comment: You can not use string indices in a list in python, use dictionary instead

Comment: A dictionary, maybe an OrderedDict, or if the list has fixed length and order a named tuple.

Comment: Maybe because they think you didn’t show extra effort in trying some code yourself, or maybe they think this is an opinion based question @David In either case you can use a dictionary as the commentors above said, take a look at my answer below

Comment: I am using dictionaries and it worked fine for me. I also understand this is a very basic question, but so are some questions software developpers ask in the statistics forum and I don't go around downvoting their questions because they don't know, for instance, what kurtosis means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commentors have mentioned, you can use `dictionary` to label your values, where the `key` is the label, and `value` is the value assigned to the label

```
In [32]: dct = {}                                                                                                              

In [33]: dct['label1'] = 'item1'                                                                                               

In [34]: dct['label2'] = 'item2'                                                                                               

In [35]: dct['label3'] = 'item3'                                                                                               

In [36]: dct                                                                                                                   
Out[36]: {'label1': 'item1', 'label2': 'item2', 'label3': 'item3'}
```

Or if you have multiple values for the same label, use a list to save all your values, and you can append the values for the label later too

```
In [37]: dct = {}                                                                                                              

In [38]: dct['label1'] = ['item11','item12']                                                                                   

In [40]: dct['label2'] = ['item21','item22', 'item23']   

In [44]: dct['label3'] = ['item31','item32', 'item33', 'item34']                                                               

In [45]: dct                                                                                                                   
Out[45]: 
{'label1': ['item11', 'item12'],
 'label2': ['item21', 'item22', 'item23'],
 'label3': ['item31', 'item32', 'item33', 'item34']}

In [51]: dct['label4'] = ['item41', 'item42', 'item43', 'item44', 'item45']                                                            

In [52]: dct['label1'].append('item13')                                                                                                

In [53]: dct                                                                                                                           
Out[53]: 
{'label1': ['item11', 'item12', 'item13'],
 'label2': ['item21', 'item22', 'item23'],
 'label3': ['item31', 'item32', 'item33', 'item34'],
 'label4': ['item41', 'item42', 'item43', 'item44', 'item45']}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add this as a comment, but I can't because reputation...

Dictionaries are the obvious answer, but maybe you should have a look at pandas dataframes. You could put your actual y in a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFramge({'y_act': y})
```

And add new predictions later:

```
df['y_SVM'] = y_pred
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late for this answer to be usefull to the particular question, but it could help others.

A python List is a collection of index-value pairs like arrays. Lists are stored sequencially, and have a predefined index ranging from 0 to n. On the contrary, dictionaries are hash tables (a type of data structure in which the address or the index value of the data element is generated from a hash function). It is a collection of label:value pairs, with no particular order. Using Dictionaries or not will be advisable deppending on your data manipulation needs.

Pandas library adds new data types, like DataFrames, but there is another usefull pandas data type: Series.

Series and Lists are both 1d ordered data structures, and both allow vector operations. The advantage is, series allows data labels. Series are in between lists and DataFrames, but labels are mandatory in Series, while optional in DataFrames. Series have better performance but less funcionalities than DataFrames.

```
pd.Series.index #allows you to access the index labels
pd.Series.values #access the stored data.
pd.Series.reindex #let you change the series indexes
```

This article discusses differences between series an dataframes: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pandas-series-vs-single-column-dataframe

Exhaustive description of series methods are described in pandas official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html